# How to change the Data Label of Syncfusion's .NET MAUI SfCircularChart to display as a percentage of the slice size?

Tags: .net, xaml, maui, syncfusion, syncfusion-chart

I have not found a property like `LabelContent` that can be set to `Percentage` which I believe is available in Xamarin? I also tried playing around with the `LabelFormat` property but there's no documentation showing examples that I've found online for .NET MAUI. The only mention of it being possible is at the bottom of [this page](https://help.syncfusion.com/maui/circular-charts/doughnutchart) but it doesn't show how it was done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by setting `LabelFormat="0'%"` of the `ChartDataLabelStyle` like below:

```
<chart:SfCircularChart>
      
            <chart:SfCircularChart.Series>
                <chart:PieSeries ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" ShowDataLabels="True" 
                                    XBindingPath="Country" 
                                    YBindingPath="Counts">
                    <chart:PieSeries.DataLabelSettings>
                        <chart:CircularDataLabelSettings>
                            <chart:CircularDataLabelSettings.LabelStyle>
                                <chart:ChartDataLabelStyle LabelFormat="0'%"/>
                            </chart:CircularDataLabelSettings.LabelStyle>
                        </chart:CircularDataLabelSettings>
                    </chart:PieSeries.DataLabelSettings>
                </chart:PieSeries>
            </chart:SfCircularChart.Series>
 </chart:SfCircularChart>
```

Below is the step you can refer to：

**#1:**
Install the [Syncfusion.Maui.Charts](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Syncfusion.Maui.Charts).

**#2:**
Register the handler in `MauiProgram.cs`:

```
 public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
        {
            var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
            builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
             //add this line
            .ConfigureSyncfusionCore()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
            });

            return builder.Build();
        }
```

**#3:**

**MainPage.xaml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiAppChart.MainPage"
               xmlns:chart="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.Maui.Charts;assembly=Syncfusion.Maui.Charts" 
             xmlns:viewModel ="clr-namespace:MauiAppChart.ViewModel"
             >

    <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="20" BackgroundColor="White" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <chart:SfCircularChart>
            <chart:SfCircularChart.BindingContext>
                <viewModel:ViewModel/>
            </chart:SfCircularChart.BindingContext>
            <chart:SfCircularChart.Legend>
                <chart:ChartLegend Placement="Right" />
            </chart:SfCircularChart.Legend>
            <chart:SfCircularChart.Title>
                <Label Text="Rural population of various countries" FontSize="Large" Margin="5,10,5,10" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"></Label>
            </chart:SfCircularChart.Title>
            <chart:SfCircularChart.Series>
                <chart:PieSeries ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" ShowDataLabels="True"
                                    XBindingPath="Country" 
                                    YBindingPath="Counts">
                    <chart:PieSeries.DataLabelSettings>
                        <chart:CircularDataLabelSettings>
                            <chart:CircularDataLabelSettings.LabelStyle>
                                <chart:ChartDataLabelStyle LabelFormat="0'%"/>
                            </chart:CircularDataLabelSettings.LabelStyle>
                        </chart:CircularDataLabelSettings>
                    </chart:PieSeries.DataLabelSettings>
                </chart:PieSeries>
            </chart:SfCircularChart.Series>
        </chart:SfCircularChart>
    </Grid>

</ContentPage>
```

**#4:**

**ViewModel.cs:**

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MauiAppChart.ViewModel
{
    public class ViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Model> Data { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<Brush> CustomBrushes { get; set; }
        public ViewModel()
        {
            Data = new ObservableCollection<Model>()
            {
                new Model("Algeria", 28),
                new Model("Australia", 14),
                new Model("Bolivia", 31),
                new Model("Cambodia", 77),
                new Model("Canada", 19),
            };

            CustomBrushes = new ObservableCollection<Brush>()
            {
               new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb("#314A6E")),
                 new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb("#48988B")),
                 new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb("#5E498C")),
                 new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb("#74BD6F")),
                 new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb("#597FCA"))
            };
        }
    }


    public class Model
    {
        public string Country { get; set; }

        public double Counts { get; set; }

        public Model(string name, double count)
        {
            Country = name;
            Counts = count;
        }
    }
}
```

**The Output:**
[image]

Comment: Sorry I edited my original question to be more specific. I meant display the size each slice takes up in the whole pie chart as a percentage, not just add a % to the value.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up emailing Syncfusion directly and they informed me there is no built-in solution for this problem. However you can override the DrawDatalabel function to achieve the same result as seen here:

```
public class DoughnutSeriesExt : DoughnutSeries

{
    protected override void DrawDataLabel(ICanvas canvas, Brush fillcolor, string label, PointF point, int index)
    {
        double totalValues = 0;
        foreach (var item in this.ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<Model>)
        {
            totalValues += item.Count;
        }

        var currentDataPoint = Double.Parse(label.Replace("%", ""));
        label = ValueToPercentage.Converter(currentDataPoint, totalValues);
        base.DrawDataLabel(canvas, fillcolor, label, point, index);
    }
}

internal static class ValueToPercentage
{
    public static string Converter(double value, double totalValue)
    {
        return Math.Round(value / totalValue * 100, 2) + "%";
    }
}
```